# Tooltip lost style in append

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip

The code to append the element is basically this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#el").on("click", function(){
      $("#class").append("\
          <!-- Add content -->\
          <div class='input-group-append' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Agregar lección'>\
              <a href='javascript:void(0)'>\
                  <span class='input-group-text btn-default'>\
                      <i class='mdi mdi-plus'></i>\
                  </span>\
              </a>\
          </div>\
      ");
      // Tooltip
      $("[data-toggle = 'tooltip']").each(function(){
         $(this).tooltip();
      });
  });
});
```

Usually the tooltip looks like this:

[image]

But after I add with append it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: You most likely have some settings you define in the `tooltip()` call when the page loads that are not set when the new tooltips are added dynamically. Alternatively it's possible the new tooltips are in a different location in the DOM where the CSS rules don't apply based on parent elements. We can't say for certain without seeing a working example of the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx for the answer! I found the problem... the jquery-ui.js was after bootstrap.min.js and occured a conflict with this files..